# JavaFX starting second GUI

Tags: java, javafx

I would like to call my LoginUI gui after I hide my create account gui below but I am having difficulty getting it to work.
Here is my createAccountUI portion:

```
package myworkouts.presentation;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import myworkouts.service.*;
import myworkouts.domain.*;

import javafx.geometry.Insets; 
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Node;

import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class CreateAccountUI extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    primaryStage.setTitle("Create Account Form JavaFX Application");

    // Create the registration form grid pane
    GridPane gridPane = createRegistrationFormPane();
    // Add UI controls to the registration form grid pane
    addUIControls(gridPane);
    // Create a scene with registration form grid pane as the root node
    Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane, 800, 500);
    // Set the scene in primary stage   
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    scene.getStylesheets().add
        (CreateAccountUI.class.getResource("Login.css").toExternalForm());          
    primaryStage.show();
}


private GridPane createRegistrationFormPane() {
    // Instantiate a new Grid Pane
    GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();

    // Position the pane at the center of the screen, both vertically and horizontally
    gridPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    // Set a padding of 20px on each side
    gridPane.setPadding(new Insets(40, 40, 40, 40));

    // Set the horizontal gap between columns
    gridPane.setHgap(10);

    // Set the vertical gap between rows
    gridPane.setVgap(10);

    // Add Column Constraints

    // columnOneConstraints will be applied to all the nodes placed in column one.
    ColumnConstraints columnOneConstraints = new ColumnConstraints(100, 100, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    columnOneConstraints.setHalignment(HPos.RIGHT);

    // columnTwoConstraints will be applied to all the nodes placed in column two.
    ColumnConstraints columnTwoConstrains = new ColumnConstraints(200,200, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    columnTwoConstrains.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);

    gridPane.getColumnConstraints().addAll(columnOneConstraints, columnTwoConstrains);

    return gridPane;
}

private void addUIControls(GridPane gridPane) {
    // Add Header

    Text headerLabel = new Text("Create Account");

    headerLabel.getStyleClass().add("header");

    gridPane.add(headerLabel, 0,0,2,1);
    GridPane.setHalignment(headerLabel, HPos.CENTER);
    GridPane.setMargin(headerLabel, new Insets(20, 0,20,0));


    // Add usernam Label
    Label usernameLabel = new Label("Username*: ");
    gridPane.add(usernameLabel, 0,1);

    // Add unsername Text Field
    TextField usernameField = new TextField();
    usernameField.setPrefHeight(40);
    gridPane.add(usernameField, 1,1);

    // Add Password Label
    Label passwordLabel = new Label("Password* : ");
    gridPane.add(passwordLabel, 0, 2);

    // Add Password Field
    PasswordField passwordField = new PasswordField();
    passwordField.setPrefHeight(40);
    gridPane.add(passwordField, 1, 2);       

    // Add confirm Password Label
    Label conpasswordLabel = new Label("Confirm pwd* : ");
    gridPane.add(conpasswordLabel, 0, 3);

    // Add confirm Password Field
    PasswordField confirmPasswordFld = new PasswordField();
    confirmPasswordFld.setPrefHeight(40);
    gridPane.add(confirmPasswordFld, 1, 3);          

    // Add  first name Label
    Label fnameLabel = new Label("First name : ");
    gridPane.add(fnameLabel, 0,4);

    // Add first name Text Field
    TextField fnameField = new TextField();
    fnameField.setPrefHeight(40);
    gridPane.add(fnameField, 1,4);

    // Add  last name Label
    Label lnameLabel = new Label("Last name : ");
    gridPane.add(lnameLabel, 0,5);

    // Add last name Text Field
    TextField lnameField = new TextField();
    lnameField.setPrefHeight(40);
    gridPane.add(lnameField, 1,5);       

    // Add Email Label
    Label emailLabel = new Label("Email ID : ");
    gridPane.add(emailLabel, 0, 6);

    // Add Email Text Field
    TextField emailField = new TextField();
    emailField.setPrefHeight(40);
    gridPane.add(emailField, 1, 6);

    // Add Required Label
    Label requireLabel = new Label("Required * ");
    gridPane.add(requireLabel, 0,8);

    // Add Submit Button
    Button createButton = new Button("Create");
    createButton.setPrefHeight(40);
    createButton.setDefaultButton(true);
    createButton.setPrefWidth(100);
    gridPane.add(createButton, 1,7);
    GridPane.setHalignment(createButton, HPos.CENTER);
    GridPane.setMargin(createButton, new Insets(20, 0,20,0));        

    // Add Cancel Button
    Button cancelButton = new Button("Cancel");
    cancelButton.setPrefHeight(40);
    cancelButton.setDefaultButton(true);
    cancelButton.setPrefWidth(100);
    gridPane.add(cancelButton, 1,7);
    GridPane.setHalignment(cancelButton, HPos.RIGHT);
    GridPane.setMargin(cancelButton, new Insets(20, 0,20,0));  

    cancelButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);              
        }
    });


    createButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            Login login = new Login();
            login.setUsername(usernameField.getText());
            login.setPassword(new String(passwordField.getText()));
            if (!login.validate()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Must supply a username & password", "Error",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }

            String confirmPassword = new String(confirmPasswordFld.getText());
            if (!confirmPassword.equals(login.getPassword())) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Passwords don't match; try again", "Error",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);                    
            return;
            } 

            Account account = new Account();
            account.setFirstName(fnameField.getText());
            account.setLastName(lnameField.getText());
            account.setLogin(login);
            boolean isValid = account.validate();
            System.out.println(isValid);
            if (!isValid) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Must supply first and last names", "Error",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                return;
            } else {
                // all the fields are non empty; create the account
                AccountSvcCacheImpl impl = AccountSvcCacheImpl.getInstance();
                account = impl.create(account);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congratulations, your account has been created", "Account created", 
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                ((Node)e.getSource()).getScene().getWindow().hide();
                // start LoginUI
                LoginUI loginUI = new LoginUI();


            }      
        }
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
    }
}
```

Here is my LoginUI:

```
package myworkouts.presentation;

import javafx.geometry.Insets; 

import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;    
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class LoginUI extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.setTitle("Forged-Fit Login");


    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    grid.setHgap(10);
    grid.setVgap(10);
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));

    Button btn = new Button("Login");
    Button resetbtn = new Button("Cancel");

    HBox hbBtn = new HBox(10);
    HBox resetBtn = new HBox(10);

    hbBtn.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
    resetBtn.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);

    hbBtn.getChildren().add(btn);
    hbBtn.getChildren().add(resetbtn);

    grid.add(hbBtn, 1, 4);
    grid.add(resetBtn, 0, 3); // might need to adjust

    final Text actiontarget = new Text();
    grid.add(actiontarget, 1, 6);

    Text scenetitle = new Text("Login");

    scenetitle.getStyleClass().add("header");

    grid.add(scenetitle, 0, 0, 2, 1);

    Label userName = new Label("Username : ");
    grid.add(userName, 0, 1);

    TextField userTextField = new TextField();
    grid.add(userTextField, 1, 1);

    Label pw = new Label("Password : ");
    grid.add(pw, 0, 2);

    PasswordField pwBox = new PasswordField();
    grid.add(pwBox, 1, 2);


    Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 400, 200);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    scene.getStylesheets().add
        (LoginUI.class.getResource("Login.css").toExternalForm());      
    primaryStage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }         
}
```

I can get the create account UI to hide with node but can't seem to figure out how to display the login UI. 
Thanks in advance! Still trying to learn JavaFX

Comment: Welcome to SO. Where do you want to invoke the `LoginUI` from ?

Comment: Why does your programm has two main methods?

Comment: @c0der I would like to invoke it just after I hide createAccountUI

Comment: @Rinat So I can run each UI independently.

Comment: For future post consider posting [mcve]

Comment: @c0der will do. thanks!

Comment: The `Application` class is the entry point of the application. You shouldn't use multiple of them (unless all of them are valid entry points)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add `loginUI.start(new Stage());` after creating LoginUI object

Comment: That was it! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `Dialog` like in the following example. 
Using a `Dialog` makes it easy to get and return input  from the user.

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar.ButtonData;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.util.Pair;

//based on:http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/
public class LoginUI extends Dialog {

    LoginUI(){

        setTitle("Login Dialog");
        setHeaderText("Look, a Custom Login Dialog");

        // Set the button types.
        ButtonType loginButtonType = new ButtonType("Login", ButtonData.OK_DONE);
        getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(loginButtonType, ButtonType.CANCEL);

        // Create the username and password labels and fields.
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(20, 150, 10, 10));

        TextField username = new TextField();
        username.setPromptText("Username");
        PasswordField password = new PasswordField();
        password.setPromptText("Password");

        grid.add(new Label("Username:"), 0, 0);
        grid.add(username, 1, 0);
        grid.add(new Label("Password:"), 0, 1);
        grid.add(password, 1, 1);

        // Enable/Disable login button depending on whether a username was entered.
        Node loginButton = getDialogPane().lookupButton(loginButtonType);
        loginButton.setDisable(true);

        // Do some validation (using the Java 8 lambda syntax).
        username.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            loginButton.setDisable(newValue.trim().isEmpty());
        });

        getDialogPane().setContent(grid);

        // Request focus on the username field by default.
        Platform.runLater(() -> username.requestFocus());

        // Convert the result to a username-password-pair when the login button is clicked.
        setResultConverter(dialogButton -> {
            if (dialogButton == loginButtonType) {
                return new Pair<>(username.getText(), password.getText());
            }
            return null;
        });
    }

    public Pair<String, String> getUserInput(){

        showAndWait();
        return (Pair<String, String>) getResult();
    }
}
```

Test it by :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Pair;

public class CreateAccountUI extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        final BorderPane p = new BorderPane();
        p.setCenter(new Label("Random label"));
        p.setPadding(new Insets(100));  // Just so window isn't too small

        final BorderPane cp = new BorderPane();
        final ToggleButton b = new ToggleButton("Show login");
        b.setOnAction(e -> {  showLogin();   });
        cp.setPadding(new Insets(50));
        cp.setCenter(b);

        final Stage control = new Stage();
        control.setScene(new Scene(cp));
        control.show();
    }


    private void showLogin() {

        LoginUI login = new LoginUI();
        Pair<String, String> result = login.getUserInput();
        if(result != null) {
            System.out.println(result.getKey() +"-"+result.getValue());
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

You can easily change your gui to extend `Dialog`.